# Single word for people having romance over skin tone, fame and money?

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

Besides for "gold digger" or "friends with benefits", is there any single word to refer to people who want to have a romance because of the other person's **money** or **fame**, or for the purpose of getting **citizenship**, or because the other person has a certain **skin tone**?

Comment: The Indian ascetics call them 'horizontals'; people attached to wealth, relations, and popularity. Of the six energy points in the body, when one is at the lowermost level, one is a horizontal. Through yogic practices one can elevate the self until he/she blends the self with the supreme. (Ref. https://iarp.org/chakra-basics/). Animals are horizontals as as they have their brain- stomach-genitals in horizontal level, unlike human beings who have brain at the top, then stomach and then comes genitals. Sorry at my inability to give more reference.

Comment: @RamPillai wow that's a broad answer and something to think too, a different perspective thanks :)

Comment: Sometimes a [**sponge**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/sponge).

Comment: opportunist, user, leech, parasite, sponge, hanger-on - https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/gold%20digger https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/self-seeker#noun

Comment: **Fortune hunter** and **visa hunter** are appropriate for money and citizen ship.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a single word that covers all the examples you give. It's tough enough to span the money-fame division.

A person attracted to money could be gold digger in one guise. In another you could shade into prostitute. Or, if it's a guy, a gigolo. You can also use various forms of mercenary.

A person attracted to fame could be called some kind of groupie. You get various forms of fan (from fancier), follower, enthusiast, etc., for whatever the famous person is famous for.

There are a number of slang terms for somebody who marries for citizenship. The specific choice will depend on the country involved. These examples are mostly appropriate to the US. For example, there is visa-whore, green-card-slut, etc. The person being used (the citizen of the target country) can be called a variety of things. Anchor baby, for example.

A person who wants a specific skin color in their romantic partner can be called a number of things. There are the obvious racist words, which I will skip. There are things like -phile. As Afrophile for example.  Some specific skin colors have particular slang terms. For example, a white guy who likes Asian women can be said to have "yellow fever."